# Add header to all files created by Unoconv

Tags: templates, pdf-generation

i am currently triying to create PDF files from different documents always with the same header. I tried using a template in unoconv but it messes all of my document.

I was wondering if anyone knows how to do this?

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved it.

You need to create an ott file with the header you would like to user and save it as template.ott

Once you have done this you need to change the command for creating PDFs to

```
unoconv -t template.ott -f pdf name_of_the_file.extension
```

But be carefull, this ott template only works for doc, docx, and odt.

The presentation files like PPT or PPTX will not work with this template.

You need to generate another template for the presentation files.

Hope this helps someone.....